# :CordovaLib:compileDebugJava FAILED - During cordova build for Android Platform

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-login, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I am using Facebook Connect Plugin for cordova.(https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)
I did all the steps as mentioned in official documentation and also from ngCordova documentation for facebook plugin. But I have been stuck with this error:

---

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14 errors

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJava'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

---

**I am using Cordova Version 5.0.0.
I am building a facebook login for android platform.**

Comment: which android target API are you building for? i've had th same problem with cordova 5 when i overrode the default android-22 with android-19. found no way to resolve other than going to android-22. and also installing it in the SDK manager of course.